# unable to access json data using RequestsLibrary of robotframework : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: robotframework

in below three test cases Get Requests1, Get Requests2 and Get Requests3. I tried to get /RestResponse/result node value by three different way but it show same error

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library  RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Get Requests1
    # create a HTTP session to a server
    Create Session  countryname  http://services.groupkt.com
    # store response
    ${resp}=  Get Request  countryname  /country/get/all
    log  ${resp.content}
    # ${resp.content} display entire json response, now tring to get node value of  /RestResponse/result
    ${getResponseJson}    Get Json Value    ${resp}    /RestResponse/result
    # shows error TypeError: expected string or buffer
    log  ${getResponseJson.content}

Get Requests2
    # create a HTTP session to a server
    Create Session  countryname  http://services.groupkt.com
    # store response
    ${resp}=  Get Request  countryname  /country/get/all
    log  ${resp.content}
    # ${resp.content} display entire json response, now tring to get node value of  /RestResponse/result
    ${responseContent}=  to json  ${resp.content}
    # shows error TypeError: expected string or buffer
    ${getResponseJson}    Get Json Value    ${responseContent}    /RestResponse/result
    log  ${getResponseJson.content}


Get Requests3
    # create a HTTP session to a server
    Create Session  countryname  http://services.groupkt.com
    # store response
    ${resp}=  Get Request  countryname  /country/get/all
    log  ${resp.content}
    # ${resp.content} display entire json response,parse json
    ${data}  Parse Json    ${resp}
    # shows error TypeError: expected string or buffer
    ${getResponseJson}    Get Json Value    ${resp}    /RestResponse/result
```

## Json file response

```
{
    "RestResponse": {
        "messages": [
            "Total [249] records found."
        ],
        "result": [
            {
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "alpha2_code": "AF",
                "alpha3_code": "AFG"
            },
            {
                "name": "\ufffd\ufffdland Islands",
                "alpha2_code": "AX",
                "alpha3_code": "ALA"
            },
            {
                "name": "Albania",
                "alpha2_code": "AL",
                "alpha3_code": "ALB"
            },
            {
                "name": "Algeria",
                "alpha2_code": "DZ",
                "alpha3_code": "DZA"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Get Json Value` from the JSON, not from the request object. In your code, `${resp}` is an object that includes the JSON data plus other things that json parsers don't know about.

```
${getResponseJson}    Get Json Value    ${resp.content}    /RestResponse/result
```

`${resp}` is a python object. It has the json data, but it also has the HTTP return code and other information. You can't pass it to anything that accepts JSON.

`${resp.content}` is the body of the HTTP response. Like you write in your comments, this is the JSON data. Any keyword that accepts JSON data should accept this.

`${resp.json}` is the JSON string of the response *converted to a python object*.  It is no longer JSON, it's a python dictionary. You cannot pass this to any function that requires JSON. You can, however, treat it like a normal python dictionary.

After running the code, `${getResponseJson}` will have the data you expect. It is a unicode string, and unicode strings don't have a `content` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried with  ${resp.content}. It shows ${getResponseJson.content}' failed: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'content'. I also tried with ${resp.json} , shows TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @madhur: Look more closely at what I typed and what you typed, and your own results. In your comments you say that `${resp.content}` shows the json string. That string is what you need to be searching for the other data. Not `${getResponseJson.content}`, and not `${resp.json}`.

Comment: No doubt, ${resp.content} shows json string. but library methods are showing error as mentioned on question when i try to access this variable.

Comment: @madhur: when I make the exact change that I mentioned in my answer, your `GetRequests1` test passes for me.